Expected date of exercise - American put
I am interested in an analytic or computational estimate of the expected date of exercise of an American put. Are there research papers (or discussions on this site) estimating the expected date upon which the holder of an American put would early exercise?
The potential dates are bounded $0 \le t \le T$, where $t=0$ is the current date and $t=T$ is the expiry of the option. What is $\textrm{E}\left(t\right)$?

I have QuantLib available if this expected date of exercise problem is solved/solvable with that toolkit.

Revision 1
I am interested in the expected date of termination
$ \textrm{E}\left( t_\textrm{termination}\right) $
for an American put contract.
$$
0 \le \textrm{E}\left( t_\textrm{termination}\right) = 
 \begin{cases}
t_\textrm{exercised} \le T &\text{if put is exercised}\\
T &  \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
My original version of this question is problematic.  An American put may be exercised up to the expiration date $T$ of the contract or not at all.

Does this answer your question? Early exercising American put options see also https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18244/american-put-for-negative-interest-rates

Thank you for your response @DimitriVulis.  The two links argue early exercise is optimal for an American put under certain conditions.  Acknowledging early exercise is optimal under certain conditions for an American put, I am interested in the expected time of optimal exercise.  Using t=0 for current time, and T=put expiry, I'm interested the expected time of optimal exercise t*: 0 <= E(t*) <= T given initial conditions (volatility, interest rate, underlying price, strike price, expiry, ...)

Hi krkeane, do you want the expectation under $\mathbb{P}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$? Also, I think there's an analytical solution to this for real options (ie, perpetual options).

Hi @Kevin - I am not familiar with the notation $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.  My immediate interest is listed US equity options.  An approximation (analytic or computational) would be of great help.  I prefer analytic solutions / approximations because they are easier for me to comprehend parameter dynamics - but, any model focused on the "expected date of termination" would be appreciated.

Does this help ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugit A related question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/57928/expected-life-fugit-of-american-option

@nbbo2 - thank you for these pointers!  I will look into comparing the approximation I posted to the Taleb method mentioned in the fugit wiki.  I never heard that word fugit before, so thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Solution concept
Assuming otherwise identical parameters, the difference in value at time $t=0$ between an American put $P_0$ and a European put $p_{~0}$ is attributable to interest earned on the strike from expected early exercise date $\bar{t}$ to expiry date $T$.
If both the American and European put are exercised, the American put holder will have the future value of the early exercised strike $K e^{r\left(T-\bar{t}\right)}$, while the European put holder will receive the strike $K$.
$$
\begin{align}
P_0 - p_{~0} &= K e^{r\left(T-\bar{t}\right)} - K \\
&\approx K \left(1 +rT -r\bar{t}\right) -K \\
\frac{P_0 - p_{~0} }{K}&\approx rT - r\bar{t}
\end{align} \\
\boxed{
\bar{t} \approx T - \frac{P_0 - p_{~0} }{rK}
}
$$

Interpretation
For a given pair of American and European puts

If $P_0=p_{~0}$, expected termination of American put is $\bar{t} = T$.
If $P_0>p_{~0}$, expected termination of American put is $0 \le \bar{t} \lt T$.


R Code
library(RQuantLib)

S <- 100     # underlying
T <- .5      # expiry
K <- 100     # strike
r <- 0.0533  # risk free rate
d <- 0       # dividend rate
sigma <- .40  # volatility

P0 <- AmericanOption(
  "put",
  underlying = S,
  strike = K,
  dividendYield = d,
  riskFreeRate = r,
  maturity = T,
  volatility = sigma
)
p0 <- EuropeanOption(
  "put",
  underlying = S,
  strike = K,
  dividendYield = d,
  riskFreeRate = r,
  maturity = T,
  volatility = sigma
)

t_bar <- T - (P0$value - p0$value) / (r * K)

cat( sprintf('P0 = %8.3f, t_bar = %6.3f\np0 = %8.3f, T     = %6.3f',
  P0$value,t_bar,p0$value,T))
#> P0 =   10.066, t_bar =  0.456
#> p0 =    9.832, T     =  0.500

Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Not an answer, but a comment on how to possibly get the expected date of exercise $E(t)$.
From what I understand, an American put is exercised early only when the spot is at zero and the put is at its max value. Otherwise, there is always time left in the option for the spot to decrease further and generate more intrinsic value for the put. It would make more sense to trade away the put option.
If one would want to determine when the spot hits zero on average/expectation, one would have to simulate the spot price evolution of the underlying and see how often it hits zero (and when the holder exercises the American put). The rest of the simulations, I suppose the holder keeps it till maturity. The expected time would then be a weighted average of the number of times the spot hits zero times their relevant time and the number of times the spot is kept till maturity and time $T$.
Hopefully this makes sense? Happy to clarify and to discuss what you think.

Thanks for your response @KaiSqDist. The simulation approach may work. Slight edit, early exercise will occur when the stock is below a boundary - that varies with time - where the value of the interest on the strike would be expected to exceed the value of further gains on the put option (see https://www.math.ucla.edu/~caflisch/181.1.07w/Lect18.pdf ).

Yup, not quite sure about the exact details of the optimal exercise point, but if you could program that into the simulated paths, I am sure it would make the estimation of $E(t)$ more accurate.

If you found my comments to be helpful, I would appreciate an upvote on my solution (or acceptance as answer unless you already have accepted another as the answer), thanks!
